# JasperReports: How to call the report in jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, jasper-reports, struts-1

I made one jasper report using `iReport 3.7.4 version`, now i have to use that or call that report in my java application where i am using servlets, jsp and struts framework, apache tomcat as server.

I want steps regarding how to call the jasper report with some example.

Answer (score 8):

1. Compile the report in iReport
2. Place the compiled report on the classpath
3. load it with

   ```
   JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(inputStream);
   ```
4. Fill it with data. `dataSource` is the `DataSource` instance you have - for example a `BeanCollectionDataSource`

   ```
   JasperPrint jasperPrint = 
        JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, dataSource);
   ```
5. Export it

   ```
   JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
   exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, outputStream);
   exporter.exportReport();
   ```
6. The `outputStream` above may be either a `response.getOutputStream()` or a `FileOutputStream()`, depending on whether you want to send it to a client or you want to store it as a file. If you want to send it to the client, you'd have to send the `Content-Disposition` header, and some more, but that depends on the format you want to save to. In case you want to *print* on the client, it's quite a different question - you'd need some client-side code, an applet, for example.

Comment: After 6 years since this was posted [JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM](http://javadox.com/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports/5.1.0/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRExporterParameter.html#OUTPUT_STREAM) has been deprecated, I have posted an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35698286/5292302) to shows how this answer is achieved in current version.

Answer (score 4):

> After 6 years @Bozho [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3747082/5292302) now (v5 and v6) contains **deprecated** code on point 5
>   [JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM](http://javadox.com/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports/5.1.0/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRExporterParameter.html#OUTPUT_STREAM), but I will try to improve the other points while I'm at it

3. **Load the report**
    **compiled** version `.jasper`

   ```
   JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(inputStream);
   ```

   or the **non compiled** version `.jrxml` (slower since need to compile but feasible)

   ```
   JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("path/to/myReport.jrxml");
   ```
4. **Fill the report** 

   with **nothing** (datasource generated inside report or just static text)

   ```
   JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params);
   ```

   with **datasource**:

   ```
   JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, dataSource);
   ```

   with database **connection** (may the most common, sql executed inside report)

   ```
   JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, connection);
   ```
5. **Export report**

   ```
   JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter()
   exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
   exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(outputStream));
   SimplePdfExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
   configuration.setMetadataAuthor("Petter"); //Set your pdf configurations, 
   exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
   exporter.exportReport();
   ```
6. If you like to **stream the report** directly to web page this is how `contentType` and `Content-disposition` is set and how you retrieve the `outputStream`

   ```
   response.setContentType("application/x-pdf");
   response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=myReport.pdf");
   OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
   ```

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code should give you some idea on how to do it

```
JasperReport jr=JasperCompileManager.compileReport("yourJRXMLFilePath");
JasperPrint jrPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr,mapWithParameters,aJRDataSource);
JasperExportManager.chooseYourFavoriteMethod(jrPrint,"destinationFile");
```

Otherwise, check the [api](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/index.html)
The first line can be ommited if you had already compiled the file with iReport. Check the api for the correct method on JasperFillManager in this case.

Answer (score 1):

in the first answer, point 5: 
After

`JRPdfExporter exporter= new JRPdfExporter();`

add

`exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);`

Answer (score 1):

Best solution (For better performance as well), will be calling a compiled report.

you can see the example below

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;

public class PdfFromJasperFile {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws JRException, IOException {

    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport("report.jasper",  new HashMap<String, Object>(), 
    new JREmptyDataSource());
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "sample.pdf");

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a different way of doing the same.

```
    JasperReport jasperReport;
    JasperPrint jasperPrint;
    Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    try{
        String sourceFileName = ".jrxml";
        jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(sourceFileName);
        jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,param,new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(getDetails()));
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, ".pdf");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
    }
```