# struts2 + hibernate3 + jasper-report 5.0 ----- getting blank report

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2, jasper-reports

i've created an application which prints out a report using jasper report 5.0, struts2 and hibernate. The jasper report uses hql.
The app works fine but the problem is that i'm getting **blank report** in browser when i triggered the struts action, but when i preview the report in netbeans i'm getting the report with datas.

can anyone please tell me some solution for this.

When report run seperately

[image]

Blank report when same report is generated through struts2 + hibernate

[image]

My code is as given below

**struts.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">

<struts>

<package name="default" extends="struts-default,jasperreports-default">
<result-types>
     <result-type name="jasper" class="org.apache.struts2.views.jasperreports.JasperReportsResult" />
</result-types>

<action name="getpdf" class="commonpackage.HibernateClass" method="getpdf">
    <result name="success" type="jasper">
        <param name="location">/Reports_HSE/sample.jasper</param>
        <param name="dataSource">myList</param>
        <param name="format">PDF</param>
    </result>
</action>

    </package>
</struts>
```

**HibernateClass.java**

```
public class HibernateClass {

private List<PeopleBean> myList;
Session session;
SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public String getpdf()
{
    String dest = ServletActionContext.getServletContext().getRealPath("/Reports_HSE/sample.jasper");
    session = createSession();

    Map parameterMap = new HashMap();
    parameterMap.put(
        JRHibernateQueryExecuterFactory.PARAMETER_HIBERNATE_SESSION, session);


    try
    {
      System.out.println("Filling report...");
      JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(dest, parameterMap);
      System.out.println("Done!");
      return "success";
    }
    catch (JRException e)
    {
      System.out.println("There was an error filling the report.");
      e.printStackTrace();
      return "error";
    }      
}
    public List getMyList() {
        return myList;
    }

  private Session createSession()
  {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure()
        .buildSessionFactory();
    return sessionFactory.openSession();
  }

}
```

**sample.jrxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="HibernateQueryDemoReport" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="30" bottomMargin="30" uuid="398cbfdc-5535-4373-bd84-38d1f6d0e677">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <parameter name="countryCode" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString language="hql">
        <![CDATA[FROM DepartmentMaster]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="abcCode1" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="abcCode2" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="deptCode" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="deptName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="status" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="createdDate" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <field name="modifiedDate" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <title>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="7c7dd6c2-fb3d-4540-a37d-9c7038a1c5ea" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="30"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Aircraft Registered in Country Code: " ]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="5bd34faa-d13d-4ac0-ab94-c86bc8950920" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[
                    Tail Number
                ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="456f1a7f-7255-4bcc-90ef-1673152ec19d" x="100" y="0" width="100" height="30"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[
                    Serial Number
                ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="84e80378-0e25-4d15-acd5-d368feda4982" x="200" y="0" width="100" height="30"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[
                    Year Built
                ]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="5cef4310-14c8-4b6b-9204-99e2fcbfae15" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="52648e98-f0cd-4f21-9f2d-2f9db2429fb4" x="100" y="0" width="100" height="30"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{deptName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="533185fe-64cf-4839-b0f8-05fbeb2b5fe9" x="200" y="0" width="100" height="30"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{deptCode}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Have you made database connection in your java code?

Comment: Yes sir , since when the struts action is triggered , in the apache console i'm getting......... `Filling report...
Hibernate: select department0_.id as id96_, department0_.dept_code as dept2_96_, department0_.dept_name as dept3_96_, department0_.abc_code1 as abc4_96_, department0_.abc_code2 as abc5_96_, department0_.status as status96_, department0_.created_date as created7_96_, department0_.modified_date as modified8_96_ from hse.department_master department0_
Done!`.......... **that shows that database is okay**

Comment: For check can you change your `id` as `id96_`. Then check that your id see in your pdf file.

Comment: do i have to declare any parameter as `id96_` or simply change the field expression `$F{id}` to `$F{id96_}`

Comment: not getting anything....still blank report......why this blank report is coming.....

Comment: I am not sure but it may be that your field name in  and its mapping name with database are not same.

Comment: ok.....but what about static label , it should print right.....even that too were not printing.....

Comment: Can you send value of parameterMap . Here is my email id:
mabtestflight@gmail.com

Comment: ok i'll send u the project.....so that you can do check wat's the prob......

Comment: Thanks for sharing... I will give you update ASAP after check it.

Comment: sir did you get the problem......

Comment: I havn't check yet, I will inform you ASAP after debugging solution.

Comment: in which IDE you made this project?

Comment: You are not populating your `myList` list.

Comment: @AleksandrM but sir.....i'm not using that list right......i'm using hql query direclty in report...........

Comment: Try to use `connection` parameter instead of `dataSource`.

Comment: but i'm using hibernate right.....in the case if we are using mysql we can pass the connection.....but how abt hibernate

Answer (score 0):

The result of

```
JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(dest, parameterMap);
```

is String with filename. This file contain jrPrint object.

How you can to see result of executing report if you dont't work with this file?

Comment: I reccomend use method fillReport. The result of fillReport is jrPrint object. After that you must make export jrPrint to PDF. See for example [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746649/jasperreports-how-to-call-the-report-in-jsp-page/3746704#3746704)

Answer (score 0):

I just recommend that you should go for

```
JasperPrint  fill(java.lang.String sourceFileName, java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object> params)
```

then, work on the return reference of JasperPrint Object. You will also be able to check whether all your data are present in it.As per documentation, `JasperPrint` - An instance of this class represents a page-oriented document that can be viewed, printed or exported to other formats.When filling report designs with data, the engine produces instances of this class and these can be transferred over the network, stored in a serialized form on disk or exported to various other formats like PDF, HTML, XLS, CSV or XML.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, so I removed the Struts2-JasperReports-Plugin jar and wrote the exporting code myself. It is very simple!

```
public void exportReport() {

    try {    

        ServletOutputStream outputStream = ServletActionContext.getResponse().getOutputStream();

        Map<string, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        parameters.put("id","1");

        //Get the parameters and report according to your application   
        byte[] bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(jasperReport, parameters, myList);


        //Setting the response as a downloadable attachment
        ServletActionContext.getResponse().setContentType("application/pdf");
        ServletActionContext.getResponse().setHeader("Content-Disposition: attachment",  "inline; filename=report.pdf");

        outputStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

    } catch(Exception e) {
        addActionError("Unable to generate report");
    }

}
```

Exporting to XLS works in a very similar manner.

Edit: Changed from connection object to datasource

Comment: In Struts2 use `stream` result for that.

Comment: I have added a little code. What kind of a sample are you looking for?